# SMB service not installed

Tags: windows-10, samba

I am trying to check if smb is running on my windows10 desktop computer.

I use this comamnd in the command prompt:

sc query smb

It is giving me error:

[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060:

De opgegeven service is geen geïnstalleerde service. (the service is not a installed service).

Does someone know how to solve this?